# Add suffix to columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to add extra word/characters to all the columns of dataframe in Python 3.6

I have data frame with 15+ columns & I want to add a word " Code" to name of all the columns exist in dataframe.

```
>>> list(dataAll)

['Active Industry Rep Count', 'Active Reps Count', 'Age Bracket', 'Channel Type', 'Count Reps Changing BDF', 'Deregistration Date During Month', 'Exclude Non Producers', 
'FileName', 'Firm', 'Firm Type', 'Gender', 'License', 'Net Rep Count', 'Quarter End', 'RIA Ownership Type', 'Registration Date During Month', 'Rep Count In', 
'Rep Count Out', 'Retail BD Primary Type', 'Retail BD Type', 'Date', 'Year End', 'Years A Rep', 'value', 'variable', 'Indicator', 'Category', 'Frequency']
```

Now I want to add " Code" to all the column except column : value & Frequency

```
ex: dataAll.rename(columns = {'Active Industry Rep Count' : 'Active Industry Rep Count Code'}, inplace = True)
```

Is it possible in single script?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to add 'Code' to the column *names*, not the values in the columns? The title suggests differently than the actual text and code.

Comment: `dataAll = dataAll.add_suffix(' Code')`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thanks working...